# how to get data from hbase through dataframe without using javaRDD

Tags: java

how to get data from Hbase  using dataframe(spark sql) without using javaRDD.
Code:-

```
SparkConf sconf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("Test");

    Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(sconf);
    try {
        HBaseAdmin.checkHBaseAvailable(conf);
        System.out.println("HBase is running");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("HBase is not running");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(jsc);

    String sqlMapping ="ROW String :ROW,city STRING r:city";
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("hbase.columns.mapping", sqlMapping);
    map.put("hbase.table", "emp1");
    DataFrame dataFrame1 = sqlContext.read().format("org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark").options(map).load();
```

Exception:-
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid value for hbase.columns.mapping 'ROW String :ROW,city STRING r:city'
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark.DefaultSource.generateSchemaMappingMap(DefaultSource.scala:119)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:109)
    at dataframe.ParquetExample.main(ParquetExample.java:94)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported column type :String

Answer (score 0):

```
    i have solve this exception "Unsupported column type :String" but 
    now getting another issue.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark.HBaseRelation.<init>(DefaultSource.scala:175)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.load(SQLContext.scala:1140)
```